# Remove Table Columns and Headers  , table having headers with a row-span and col-span using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table and need to remove its columns using jquery. Using this but it removes all the headers , but I want that only the first row header is removed.

```
   <table border="2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
    <tr>
           <th rowspan="2">#</th>
           <th rowspan="2">A</th> 
           <th rowspan="2">B</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="3">C</th>
    </tr>
<tr>

           <th>C-1</th>
           <th>C-2</th> 
           <th>C-3</th>
</tr>

<tr>

           <td>CONTENT</td>
           <td>CONTENT</td>
           <td>CONTENT</td>        
           <td>CONTENT</td>
           <td>CONTENT</td> 
           <td>CONTENT</td> 
</tr>


</table>
```

I need to remove the column A , and its corresponding tds , so am using :

```
$('tr td:nth-child(2), tr th:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

It removes the TH - A and its column CONTENT but the `<th>` : C-2  also gets also removed , please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly You have an extra `tr` at the top of your code. Remove that and then you can using the 
[`first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector to accomplish what you want for this specific html structure like this

```
$('tr td:nth-child(2), tr:first-child > th:nth-child(2)').remove();​
```

**Explanation**

the selector which is excluding `C-2` is `tr:first-child > th:nth-child(2)`. The thing it telling jQuery is `find the first tr` then `find the 2nd th` . The `>` is to mean find `th` which are inside(or children of ) `tr`. As `C-2` is in second `tr` it's being excluded. Let me know if that makes sense to you. I am not very good at writting.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/Pwwkb/)

which changes the color of your desired elements. Use remove instead in your code.

Comment: sir , its working on the demo, but in my code it doens't work

Comment: Did you remove the extra `tr` at the top of your html code. or please paste your html code in http://pastie.org/ and share the link So I can have a look

Comment: can a Table ID be specified in this?

Comment: Yeah sure you can. just add `#TABLE_ID` at the starting of each selector. Then it will search in that table only. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11464/discussion-between-joy-and-sqlchild)